# Configuration of iqaudio digiamp+ on Matlab

Tags: linux, alsa, audio-playback, matlab, simulink

I try to implement a simple Simulink-model on my Raspberry Pi 4 model b . For this, I have a simple sine wave with 1/8000 sample time wich I pluged into an ALSA Audio Capture Block.

When I try to run it on the Pi, I get following error:

Error:A run-time error is encountered when running External mode simulation on the Raspberry Pi hardware. This usually occurs when a hardware resource, such as a web camera or an audio card, is not available or configured incorrectly. The log file, /home/pi/MATLAB_ws/R2023a/ALSA_playback_test.log, storing model diagnostic information on the Raspberry Pi hardware has the following content: **** Starting the application ****
Path = /home/pi/MATLAB_ws/R2023a/C/Users/...
Channel count (1) not available for playback: Invalid argument
Error setting number of channels to (1): Invalid argument
Error setting audio hardware parameters for 'hw:3,0': Invalid argument

I already checked the connection of the Audio Board and used the 'aplay' command on the Pi's terminal:

aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: Headphones [bcm2835 Headphones], device 0: bcm2835 Headphones [bcm2835 Headphones]
Subdevices: 8/8
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
Subdevice #1: subdevice #1
Subdevice #2: subdevice #2
Subdevice #3: subdevice #3
Subdevice #4: subdevice #4
Subdevice #5: subdevice #5
Subdevice #6: subdevice #6
Subdevice #7: subdevice #7
card 1: vc4hdmi0 [vc4-hdmi-0], device 0: MAI PCM i2s-hifi-0 [MAI PCM i2s-hifi-0]
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: vc4hdmi1 [vc4-hdmi-1], device 0: MAI PCM i2s-hifi-0 [MAI PCM i2s-hifi-0]
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 3: IQaudIODAC [IQaudIODAC], device 0: IQaudIO DAC HiFi pcm512x-hifi-0 [IQaudIO DAC HiFi pcm512x-hifi-0]
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

The ressource monitor also detects the Audioboard:
[image]

I also executed some test sounds with the Pi's terminal like 'speaker-test -Dplughw:3,0...' and got a test sound.

It appears, that Matlab itself can't detect the hardware, for example if I use the listAudioDevices(r,'playback') (r is the Pi with its IP-adress, user name and pw) I get following error:

a = listAudioDevices(r,'playback')
Index exceeds the number of array elements. Index must not exceed 0.

Error in listAudioDevices>getHWParams (line 96)
c = tmp(index(1));

Error in listAudioDevices (line 81)
[numChannels, Format, Rate] = getHWParams(hwParams);

On the other hand, for adio capture it works and creates an array.

(line 81 of the function: % Populate the struct with new details
[numChannels, Format, Rate] = getHWParams(hwParams);)

(line 96 of the function:  c = tmp(index(1));)

If someone has a solution or faced the same problem, I would be glad for your help.

I already updated driver.